# "Invalid authentication data. Connection reset" When trying to log in to github within IntelliJ

Tags: authentication, github, intellij-idea

Whenever I try to log into github from IntelliJ, [I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYUJA.png)

Even thought my authentication data is correct, it tells me it's not. And it doesn't matter if I use a token or just use my credentials. I get the same problem. I've tried to delete all tokens and generated a new one, this also didn't change anything. What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be caused by some proxy in the middle. `Invalid authentication data` is a generic message that appears when call to GitHub API fails without clear reasons. `Connection reset` seems to be the real message, and could be caused by some proxy or network firewall.

Check the logs for more details on the error. If you think it is some bug in IntelliJ, it is worth reporting the issue to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ with logs attached.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed had to set the proxy of my company in the settings.